# Oracle import (impdp) issue in full mode

Tags: oracle, import, impdp

I am a DBA starter first of all. From a source i am able to do oracle export by full, table and schema wise. But now am stuck in import utiliy for full database import(looking for full import).

I tries this:

```
impdp system/******** FULL=y DIRECTORY=exp_dir DUMPFILE=fulldb_exp.dmp LOGFILE=fulldb_imp.log
```

Later on i found that its not enough to import fully. Beacuase The import could not create tablespaces, users nor any objects. So i tried to create them with SQLFILE parameter which helps to run sql script to create tablespaces and all. But when i run the scripts am getting error ***"ERROR at line 2:ORA-02236: invalid file name"***

Please help me to slove this. 
Am using 12c instance from server to 12c pc

Answer (score 0):

This might happen when `DATAFILE` does not have a value, you can probably see that in SQL listed in the error message, something like:

```
CREATE BIGFILE TABLESPACE "NAME_OF_TABLE_SPACE" DATAFILE SIZE 1258291200 AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 1258291200 ...
```

When no `DATAFILE` is given, Oracle will try to create a datafile at the default location. If that location is not set, `CREATE` will fail.

You can check the default location for tablespaces with

```
SQL> show parameter DB_CREATE_FILE_DEST;

NAME                  TYPE     VALUE
--------------------- -------- ------------------------------
db_create_file_dest   string
```

Above, it has no value. To set the value, use `alter system set`:

```
SQL> alter system set DB_CREATE_FILE_DEST='/ORCL/u02/app/oracle/oradata/ORCL/orclpdb1';

System altered.

SQL> show parameter DB_CREATE_FILE_DEST;

NAME                  TYPE     VALUE
--------------------- -------- ------------------------------------------
db_create_file_dest   string   /ORCL/u02/app/oracle/oradata/ORCL/orclpdb1
```

Here, `/ORCL/u02/app/oracle/oradata/ORCL/orclpdb1` is the path for tables spaces in the first pluggable database (PDB), using the Oracle 12.2.0.1 container from https://container-registry.oracle.com/